# How to upgrade Git on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, git

How do I upgrade Git on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the latest git on your system, add this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) in your software sources. Then install git-core if it wasn't done before, and update your system.

However I would suggest to upgrade to an unsupported package only if you **require** some specific features included only in the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you already have it installed and everything is clean.

If you want the absolute newest version and that is not in the repositories, there is a guide to doing that here:
http://ropiku.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/updating-git-on-ubuntu/

Comment: that tutorial you linked worked great for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just to summarize:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the newest question, but I found myself asking the same and the only thing that worked was installing from the github repositories following [the guide from the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git), which I guess is the most reliable when it comes to updates and changes anyway.