# How to upgrade Git on Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I have Git version 1.5.4.3 installed, but I think this must be an old version. I'm running Ubuntu Hardy 8.04. I need to install at least version 1.6 to get a Git GUI to work. How do I upgrade my installation?

**Update:** I managed to upgrade my installation of Git, but I also realized that my version of Ubuntu was old so I upgraded to the newest version, which automatically gave me access to newer packages (including Git).

Comment: Which ubuntu version?

Comment: This is already answered on Superuser http://superuser.com/questions/55542/how-to-upgrade-git-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I used the PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers to update Git from 1.5.4.3 on Hardy to 1.6.5.2.
No compiling, just add another entry to your sources list, apt-get update and you're good to go.

```
https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa
```

More info on the page (Technical details > Read about installing).

Or just run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: What is the point of the `python-software-properties` install?

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't know anymore since this answer is 3 years old... probably the package is needed to install `git`. You can try installing without it, if it's needed, `apt-get` will complain.

Comment: I thought add-apt-repository was introduced in karmic (9.10) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: I do not know how you managed to use add-apt-repository on hardy, but it didn't work on my 8.04 server even after a complete update. So I am publishing my own instructions, just in case someone found the same problem.

Comment: See my comment on your answer for a tip on how to get `add-apt-repository` working.

Answer (score 18):

To update git to newer version in ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

i am using ubuntu 10.04.2 Lucid

Comment: Awesome, this should be the merged with the correct answer (IMHO) because it uses the distribution tools that are in place for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Might need to `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`
first if `add-apt-repository` doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

[This tutorial](http://ropiku.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/updating-git-on-ubuntu/) worked great for me. Here's what you should do:

Download the newest version from [the Git website](http://git-scm.com/) to your home directory and extract it.

Open up the terminal and enter the following commands (one at a time):

```
sudo apt-get remove git git-svn
sudo apt-get build-dep git-core
cd git-1.6.5/ (or whatever version you downloaded and extracted)
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You should now have the newest version of Git installed.

Comment: ..and it's installed bypassing the packet management, so you are on your own with future updates. Not to say it's all bad - I just prefer installing packages over compiling whenever I can.

Comment: Now it's better just to clone and fetch the latest from github: https://github.com/git/git.git. Checkout the tag with the latest version.

Comment: This is totally not needed. The package manager has an *official* way to introduce new versions in the system. This is just hacking around it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Which ubuntu are you on? Hardy is still on version 1.5.4.3 for example. You may be able to install the version from one of the newer releases of ubuntu though

Comment: I think I'm on Hardy since I am still on version 1.5.4.3

Comment: I was able to install a newer version of Git on Hardy by doing it manually. Is that ok? Or is there a reason Hardy is still on version 1.5.4.3?

Answer (score 2):

All packadges can be found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git-core

```
cd /tmp    
sudo apt-get install liberror-perl libdigest-sha1-perl
wget --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/git-core_1.7.0.4-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i git-core_1.7.0.4-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Git 1.6 is available starting with Jaunty: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git-core

So if you don't want to compile/install the package yourself, you'll need to upgrade your system to a newer ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

I did this on Hardy with the following commands:

```
wget http://www.backports.org/debian/pool/main/g/git-core/git-core_1.6.3.3-1~bpo50+1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i git-core_1.6.3.3-1~bpo50+1_i386.deb
```

If somebody knows some reason not to do it this way, please comment.

Comment: This is interesting. Why use backports? Does this automatically keep the package updated?

Comment: One reason not to do it that way is because you're not using Debian.  Another reason not to do it that way is because you shouldn't be manually running "dpkg -i".  If you want a backport, go through the backport request process for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Answer (score 0):

First thing, try running the software update utility and see if it's got a new version for you.  Alternatively, as root,

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

If that fails, you could try finding a backported version of git such as [this one](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2009/07/29/update-package-git-1-6-4-for-ubuntu-jaunty/)

If that for whatever reason does not work for you, you could download the source files from the git webpage.  Ensure you have build-essential installed ---

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

and then if it is anything like any other reasonable package,

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: don't use make install. Use checkinstall. It turns the result of your make install into a deb file that allows the package manager to track the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to do this?

```
sudo apt-get build-dep git-core
```

on a newly installed Karmic tries to install 560MB/137 packages

https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa is the way to go specially for ease of updates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Manuel Meurer was good, but it didn't work for me since my updated Ubuntu 8.04 "Hardy" has no add-apt-repository command, and it seems to not exist in no package.

So, these are my own instructions just in case someone founds the same problem:

Create a file called 'git.list' within /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with the following content:

```
    deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu hardy main 
    deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu hardy main
```

Then exec:

```
    sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24
```

And then:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install git
```

If you notice dependency problems during the install, then try this before the previous apt-get commands:

```
    sudo apt-get purge git git-core
```

Comment: Try this to get `add-apt-repository` working: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-software-properties && sudo dpkg-reconfigure python-software-properties`